# Backend Error on Hide-o-matic

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to use the google play game tools to hide cheaters from my game's leaderboards.
I can successfully list the current high scores and all, but when I try to hide a specific player, it returns me this backend error message.

The account I'm used is set as a tester, and I'm using the public dropbox folder as host, not sure if that's ok.

[image]

Comment: Have you linked your app in the Play Games developer console?

Comment: I did. And I did it from the Play Games console as advised. I'm not sure if I did it right though. Here is how it looks like from the developer console: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42072982/image_share/hideomatic-credential-dev-console.png

Comment: I am pretty sure the APP_ID and Leaderboard ID are fine because it correctly lists all players. AFAIK the other ID I must input the the tool is the Client ID in the scorer.html, which I guess is fine too:
data-clientid="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"

Comment: Did you try running it on local host instead of dropbox?

Comment: No, but I've tried it from another one of my personal hosts and I've got the same behaviour. But it turns out it can be a bug that started in a recent push. Here's the official issue: https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools/issues/4
I'll keep you posted and in case it happens to be the case, I'll post the answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a backend bug, and it seems to be fixed by now. Here is the official issue: https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools/issues/4